# Cannot Access uploaded file with XHR - laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, xmlhttprequest

I use laravel with [LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader](https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader) to upload files with xhr requests.

however, i cannot access uploaded file with

```
Input::file('name') // or eaither 
Input::get('name')
```

i get NULL for both.

how i can access uploaded file with xhr request.

here is my JS code:

```
var sizeBox = document.getElementById('sizeBox'), // container for file size info
    progress = document.getElementById('progress'); // the element we're using for a progress bar

    var uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
      button: 'upload-btn', // file upload button
      url: '{{action('filesController@postPicUpload')}}', // server side handler
      name: 'myfile', // upload parameter name        
      progressUrl: 'uploadProgress.php', // enables cross-browser progress support (more info below)
      responseType: 'json',
      allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
      maxSize: 1024, // kilobytes
      hoverClass: 'ui-state-hover',
      focusClass: 'ui-state-focus',
      startXHR: function(){
          console.log('startXHR');
      },
      startNonXHR: function(){
        console.log('startNonXHR');  
      },
      disabledClass: 'ui-state-disabled',
      onSubmit: function(filename, extension) {
          this.setFileSizeBox(sizeBox); // designate this element as file size container
          this.setProgressBar(progress); // designate as progress bar
        },         
      onComplete: function(filename, response) {
          console.log(response);
          if (!response) {
              alert(filename + 'upload failed');
              return false;            
          }
          // do something with response...
        }
    });  
    });
```

and here is my action:

```
public function postPicUpload(){
        $file = Input::file('myfile');
        $file->move('imgs/'.date('Y/n/j/', time()),$file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
```

any help?

Comment: Have you tried  Input::hasFile('myfile')

Comment: yes i tried but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in a normal form I forgot to add in form data.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: not working, actually i figure out my upload script using XHR stream.